# Distinguish between glucose and Fructose samples

Tags: carbohydrates

I am looking for a simple way to distinguish between glucose and fructose samples. Currently, I am doing that by melting temperature method. Can anybody suggest me some easy way to do that?

Comment: Related: [Why does fructose reduce Tollen's reagent and Fehling's solution?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40127/7951)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the simplest ways would be bromine-water test. Bromine water oxidizes glucose to gluconic acid, hence decolorize the solution. Being a mild oxidizing agent, Bromine water is not capable of oxidizing fructose (ketone).

Answer (score 4):

Go for Seliwanoff's Test. It is based on the simple fact that when heated, ketose sugars are more rapidly dehydrated than aldoses. After acidic hydrolysis of both, we add a pinch of resorcinol(0.5%) and concentrated HCl(3N). Fructose reacts to give a deep red cherry colour whereas Glucose reacts slightly to produce a faint pink colour.

Comment: Why are ketoses more easily dehydrated than aldoses?

Answer (score 1):

Taste tests also work. Fructose is about 2.3 times sweeter tasting than glucose, and the tongue is a very good sweet-sensor.

[image]

(source: wikipedia)

Comment: While this is accurate, normally one does not recommend tasting chemicals in a laboratory.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Osazone test.... add phenylhetrazine +sodium acetate + acetic acid...if yellow precipitate appears within two minutes of boiling in waterbath (needle shape crystals)then the sample is Fructose.. if yellow precipitate appears between 5 to 10 minutes of boiling in waterbath (broom shaped crystals)its glucose.