# In what way could benzoin give Tollen's test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-oxidation

In Q29 of [Joint Entrance Exam (JEE) 2016 India](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxIR7Kj71SMKd0V2UlBMYVJpRHM), the official answer key mentions that benzoin gives Tollen's test. However, I saw this post which says that it doesn't: [Why do α-hydroxy ketones give Tollens' test?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73313/why-do-%CE%B1-hydroxy-ketones-give-tollens-test)

Benzoin:

[image]

I'm very confused now. If benzoin does give the test, how? And what is the mechanism/intermediate involved?

I thought of all possible reactions benzoin may undergo in basic medium:

- I did its aldol condensation but the product was too crowded and seemed quite unlikely. It didn't have any aldehyde group.
- Another possibility seemed oxidation to benzil, but I'm not sure. I don't think $\ce{Ag+}$ is strong enough.
- I was thinking about cleavage of central $\ce{C-C}$ single bond — as the hydroxyl $\ce{O}$ donated its lone pair to the carbon it is attached to, but am not sure on this too.

I couldn't find any related reaction of benzoin or any rearrangement on the internet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Of your three "thoughts", you are correct that an aldol reaction is not an option. Not only is the product "crowded", but the reaction is reversible. [BTW, an *aldol condensation* occurs when water is eliminated from the initial aldol product. In the case of a benzoin aldol product, elimination of water is impossible.]

Your second premise is a good one. Benzoin (**1**) in the presence of alkaline Tollens' reagent, can be enolized (blue arrows) and the hydroxyl group deprotonated (red arrows). The enediolate **2** is a prime candidate for oxidation by Ag<sup>+</sup>. This species is the dianion of the enediol **6** tautomer of benzoin. The enediolate **2** is formed in the [acyloin condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyloin_condensation) of ethyl benzoate (**7**).
A one-electron oxidation of the enediolate **2** produces resonance stabilized radical anion **3**. Protonation of **3** may occur at this point but a second one-electron oxidation produces the diradical **4**, which is benzil (**5**). Under more vigorous alkaline conditions, Liebig's [benzylic acid rearrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzilic_acid_rearrangement) of benzil occurs to afford benzylic acid (**8**), which itself is known to oxidize to benzophenone (**9**) under a variety of oxidative decarboxylation conditions. Neither of these reactions, i.e., the formation of **8** and **9**, is expected to occur under the mild conditions of the Tollens' oxidation. Accordingly, your third idea is unlikely under the reaction conditions.

[image]

Comment: Can you please specify the source of your answer? In particular of the fact that benzil does form??

Comment: And.. Not all alpha hydroxy ketones will do this(i.e. get oxidised ).. Am  i right on this??

Comment: I cannot attest that ALL acyloins react with Tollens to give alpha-diketones. Here is an example: Tetrahedron Letters, (1969), 33, 2823.  Acyloins are readily oxidized by Bi2O3, Cr+6, V oxidants, etc.

Comment: here a double bond in conjugation with 2 phenyl rings is being formed, and also a benzyl radical ... i cannot open the Tetrahedron Letters link as i don't have access .. can you send me the paper on email (vishesh.jain331990@gmail.com)  ..? @user55119

Comment: have you found any other compounds or acyloins that give a positive test ..? @KavitaJuneja

Comment: https://youtu.be/xlaKvKfNidA
This clearly shows the thing