# Why does 3-hydroxy-butan-2-one give positive Tollens' test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation, reagents

Why does [3-hydroxy-butan-2-one](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/acetoin#section=Top) give a positive [Tollens' test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollens%27_reagent) despite the absence of an aldehyde group? What is the mechanism?

[image: Sturcture of 3-hydroxy-butan-2-one]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Wikipedia entry on Tollens [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollens%27_reagent)

> Tollens' reagent is a chemical reagent used to determine the presence of an aldehyde, aromatic aldehyde and **alpha-hydroxy ketone** functional groups

The substrate you have drawn is an alpha-hydroxy ketone.

Comment: answered here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94620/in-what-way-could-benzoin-give-tollens-test

Comment: I have no access to a drawing package

Comment: @Abcd: What do you mean by "very vastly presented" and " the specific mechanism" in regard to Waylander's link? Aldehydes are oxidized by Tollens' reagent. So are some other functionalities. A positive test MAY indicate the presence of an aldehyde.