# Various pathways of an alpha diketone reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, aldol-reaction, carboxylic-acids

> [image]

This is a question from JEE Advanced 1997.

I have found two possible products of the reaction:

> 1. By intramolecular aldol condensation:
>
> [image]
>
> 2. By benzil-benzilic acid type rearrangement:
>
> [image]

Which reaction takes place here?

Comment: #1 is a very strained species, whereas the benzil-benzilic acid rearrangement is a well-precedented pathway. Occam's razor applies. Your choice.

Comment: @Waylander I agree! However, I wonder if there is any stabilizing effect on that...

Comment: I don't think there is enough stabilisation to make #1 a viable product.

Comment: Furthermore there is very little literature mention of 2-phenylcyclopropenone - it if could be prepared by this route then there would be multiple examples.

Comment: There is something [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94620/in-what-way-could-benzoin-give-tollens-test/94630#94630) that will be of use.